# How to make pandas str.contains (don't have to be starts with) query 2 letter consecutively

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, contains

Here's my dataset

```
Id sitename
1  BERASAMA
2  LTE_RS_HARAPAN
3  RSA_IBU
4  OFFICE
```

Here's my code

```
filter = df[df['sitename'].str.contains("RS")]
```

What I Expect

```
Id sitename
2  LTE_RS_HARAPAN
3  RSA_IBU
```

Reality

```
Id sitename
1  BERASAMA
2  LTE_RS_HARAPAN
3  RSA_IBU
```

I Know that "BERASAMA" is contain `R` and `S` and not consecutively

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`str.startswith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html):

```
out = df[df['sitename'].str.startswith("RS")]
```

Output:

```
   Id    sitename
1   2     RS_HARAPAN
2   3     RSA_IBU
```